# vue-awesome-swiper and callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback, vue.js, vuejs2, swiper.js

I'm using Vue.js 2 and vue-awesome-swiper.

I would like to do at least one of these two things on the callback of the swiper `onSlideChangeEnd(swiper)`

1. Be able to trigger the function `onSwipe()`
2. Access to `this.private.privateData`

I think the underlying problem is that I don't know how to access the `this` which represents not the swiper nor the object touchEventsTarget but my `App.vue`.

When I tries to do `this.private.privateData` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'orderFilter' of undefined` which makes sense.

What should I do ? Thank you.

#### App.vue

```
  <template>
  <swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper">
    <!-- slides -->
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 2</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'carrousel',
    data() {
      return {
        private: {
            privateData : 'private'
        },
        swiperOption: {

          notNextTick: true,
          setWrapperSize :true,
          autoHeight: true,
          onSlideChangeEnd(swiper) {

               ***** DO SOMETHING HERE *****
          },
        }
      }
    },

   methods : {
     onSwipe() {console.log('Swiped')};
   },
    computed: {
      swiper() {
        return this.$refs.mySwiper.swiper
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('this is current swiper instance object',this.swiper)

    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused why you get an undefined `orderFilter`. I don't see a reference anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a closure.

```
  data(){
    const vue = this;
    return {
      private: {
        privateData : 'private'
      },
      swiperOption: {
        notNextTick: true,
        setWrapperSize :true,
        autoHeight: true,
        onSlideChangeEnd:function(){
          console.log(vue.private.privateData);
          vue.onSwipe()
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Would this have worked too?  `onSlideChangeEnd(() => { this.onSwipe(); })`

Comment: @subdigit I would think so.